# I'm getting an error "Error type 'AuthResult' is not a subtype of type 'FirebaseUser' in type cast" when I'm trying to login or signup

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm making a flutter app for my college project, where I'm adding a login and signup page and authenticating it via Firebase, and when I click login the debug console says **"Error type 'AuthResult' is not a subtype of type 'FirebaseUser' in type cast"** and when I reload the app after this error it successfully logs in.

Everything was working best before the update of the **firebase_auth** package to 0.12.0 after this update, the methods "signInWithEmailAndPassword()" and "createUserWithEmailAndPassword()" throwing an error **"A value of type 'AuthResult' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FirebaseUser'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'FirebaseUser'"**, so I added a cast **as FirebaseUser** which fixed the error and the app was built successfully but when i clicked on login or create account, debug console said **Error type 'AuthResult' is not a subtype of type 'FirebaseUser' in type cast**

the main login and create account function code before the update of firebase_auth 0.12.0

```
Future<String> signIn(String email, String password) async {
FirebaseUser user = await 
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email, password: password);
return user.uid;
}

Future<String> createUser(String email, String password) async {
FirebaseUser user = await 
FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email, password: password);
return user.uid;
}
```

the above code was working fine,
after the update (firebase_auth 0.12.0) the same code started throwing this error,

```
A value of type 'AuthResult' can't be assigned to a variable of type 
'FirebaseUser'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 
'FirebaseUser'.dart(invalid_assignment)
```

I fixed the error by casting "FirebaseUser" as shown below

```
Future<String> signIn(String email, String password) async {
FirebaseUser user = await 
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email, password: password) as FirebaseUser;
return user.uid;
}

Future<String> createUser(String email, String password) async {
FirebaseUser user = await 
FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email, password: password) as FirebaseUser;
return user.uid;
}
```

this new code didn't threw an error in compilation but when I try to login or create new account it throws an error in debug console 
    Error type 'AuthResult' is not a subtype of type 'FirebaseUser' in type 
    cast
and the new created account is successfully created on firebase but the app doesn't go on the next page but as soon as i reload it starts with the page that should come after login and creation of account(sign out is working perfectly)

Answer (score 25):

This is a breaking change in the plugin and its documented here 
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth#0120

So you shouldn't do any type of casting you just have to refactor your code to adopt the new changes :

```
FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.
signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password))
.user;
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your help that worked for me, now there is no error but still it's not switching to the Homepage(the page which supposed to come after login), the debug console says "Signed in" no error but doesn't go ahead either. I hope you can help

Comment: I think this might be another issue but not related to firebase_auth and in your question, you don't mention how you are doing the transition to the `homepage ` . i guess you better make that in another question

Comment: I do have a homescreen but this part was only a bussiness logic. And can you help me live tracking in flutter?

Answer (score 18):

I face the same issue. Just modify to be:

`final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;`

See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38757#issuecomment-522307525

Comment: You just saved me hours of trouble. God bless you!

Answer (score 7):

The classes have been renamed. 'AuthResult' has been renamed to 'UserCredential' and 'FirebaseUser' is renamed to 'User'.

Answer (score 5):

I had same error and changed code to:

```
FirebaseUser user = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)).user;
```

The app works as expected on a real device, without an error in the console, but Visual Studio Code shows red underline at the end below user and outputs an error:

> The getter 'user' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseUser'.
>   Try importing the library that defines 'user', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'user'.

**[Solution]** Restart VS Code. VS Code uses the old library until restart.

Comment: After restartarting VS code the error persisted, however restarting my computer did the trick. Thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

- use User instead of FirebaseUser on firebase_auth 0.18.0+1

  ```
  final User user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: 'abc@gmail.com',
                  password: 'abc',
                 )).user;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

It has been changed what you should do is 
`AuthResult result = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
         email: email, password: password);
     FirebaseUser user = result.user;`

Answer (score 1):

**signInWithEmailAndPassword** returns **AuthResult** and **AuthResult** class contains instance variable **user** of type **FirebaseUser**.
So You have to change your code as following way.

```
FirebaseUser userDetails = (await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(Credentialsxxx)).user;
print('sign in : ${userDetails.uid}');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to us `UserCredential` instead of `AuthResult`.
Firebase has deprecated AuthResult.
Maybe you will find some useful information in [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63482162/undefined-class-firebaseuser).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30901349)