# Firebase Doesn't show any user

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm currently using Firebase_Auth. all seems fine when I click the login button and the Firebase is connected to my app. it shows user's Id on the terminal. but when I go to firebase.

It doesn't recognize any user that been registered.

Ps: the problem is when the user is registered it doesn't show to the firebase.

```
 void validateAndSubmit() async {
    if (validateAndSave()) {
      try {
        if(_formType == FormType.login){ 
        final FirebaseUser user = ( await FirebaseAuth.instance
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password))
            . user;
        print('Signed in: ${user.uid}');
      } else {
       final FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)) . user;
        print('Registered user: ${user.uid}');
         }
      }
       catch (e) {
        print('Error: $e');
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: have you enabled sign up with email?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, check this one out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57306500

```
void validateAndSubmit() async {
if (validateAndSave()) {
  try {
    FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password))
        .user;
    print('Signed in: ${user.uid}');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
  }
}
}
```